# Jquery to Check Data Annotations

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I added custom jquery validation to MVC Data Annotations validations. But i am not sure, how to call validation on clicking submit?

On using the code below the form is getting submitted eventhough the validation fails

```
            $("input[type=file]").change(function () {
            var ext = $(this).val();
            ext = ext.substring(ext.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp']) == -1) {
                $(".validation-summary-errors").css("color", "red").show();
                $(".validation-summary-errors ul").append("<li>Choose only image files</li>");
            }
            else {
                $(".validation-summary-errors ul li:contains('Choose only image files')").remove();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can be more specific with your question buddy ?

Comment: Can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: @dreamweiver, how to fiddle this? The issue related with `DataAnnotations` in mvc?